# method .focus() on Bing Maps v8

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm doing a migration from Bing Maps v7 to v8.
I need to "translate" the **.focus()** method.
How can I do this on Bing v8?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you need to accomplish, it isn't clear. .focus is a standard function in JavaScript and not Bing Maps specific.

Comment: this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427609.aspx#Anchor_3

"focus -
focus() -
None -
Applies focus to the map control so that it responds to keyboard events."

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem using the jQuery's method ".focus"

Comment: Ok, the focus function that was on the map control itself was removed as it really wasn't needed as all it did was grab the map div and use the standard javascript focus function. At the end of the day it didn't reduce the amount of code you would write and just added extra code to download. You can easily do this like so: document.getElementById("myMap").focus();